# Improve SQL Query with Inner Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I wrote this query, which will count the number of rows grouped by some values 
I've created a stored procedure that will return four columns. Some times I get the "Timeout" error message. Here is the query :

[How tables are related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy7Y8.png)
[image: How tables are related]

```
  SELECT Orders_Header.ProjectNumber, Orders_Header.CostCategory,COUNT(Orders_Samples.SampleValue) AS AmountOfSamples, Activities.Area
    FROM  Orders_Header 
   INNER JOIN Orders_Sequence 
      ON Orders_Header.OrderID = Orders_Sequence.OrderID 
   INNER JOIN Orders_Samples 
      ON Orders_Header.OrderID = Orders_Samples.OrderID 
     AND Orders_Samples.ActivityNumber = Orders_Sequence.ActivityNumber 
   INNER JOIN Activities 
      ON Orders_Header.Plant = Activities.Plant 
     AND Orders_Sequence.ActivityName = Activities.ActivityName
   WHERE (Orders_Header.ClosingDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @FinishDate) 
     AND (Orders_Header.Plant = @Plant) 
     AND (Orders_Sequence.ActivityName = @ActivityName) 
     AND (Area = @Area)
   GROUP BY Orders_Header.ProjectNumber, Orders_Header.CostCategory, Activities.Area
```

I want to improve this query as best as I can, so if someone will give me an example, please explain those examples. (I'm a beginner to SQL)

I've searched the internet and I there was a suggestion to look for the execution plan.

[Excecution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wj00.png)
[image: Excecution Plan]

In the execution plan I get this message: "Missing Index Details"

```
USE [Orders]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Orders_Sequence] ([ActivityName],[Rating])
INCLUDE ([OrderID],[ActivityNumber])
GO
```

Comment: Tag dbms product use, and you'll get better attention and probably also better answers, faster.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard `[..]` and the `GO` keyword

Comment: move where clause to inner join ... that will speed it up, and also those parameters move to local variables for parameter sniffing .. that should speed your procedure by mile

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response, but can you be more specific ?